# What is MATM in my User-agent

Tags: internet-explorer-10, user-agent

The most used IE User-agent's in my stats are:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; MATM)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
```

What does the MATM stand for?

Comment: I have seen a lot of weird expressions from IE user agent strings before too. I tried to look for MATM for the past 15 minutes with no results. My guess would be some specific version of the browser or a plugin in the browser.

Comment: It's likely to be a plugin of some sort, but given that it's possible for the User Agent string to be completely made up by the client, it could be anything. It's perfectly possible that it's not even IE10.

Comment: [This site](http://www.whatismybrowser.com/developers/unknown-user-agent-fragments) suggests it might be a manufacturer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATM is a codename for the hardware, one of several by the same vendor:

```
  useragent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; MATMJS)
  vendor: TS
-
  useragent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; MATM)
  vendor: TS
-
  useragent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; MATP)
  vendor: TS
-
  useragent: Mozilla/5.0 (MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MATBJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
  vendor: TS
-
  useragent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; MATPJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
  vendor: TS
-
  useragent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; TNJB; rv:11.0) like Gecko
  vendor: TS
-
  useragent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; Touch; TAJB; rv:11.0) like Gecko
  vendor: TS
```

Where TS is Toshiba:

```
'TS' => 'Toshiba',
```

Use the following registry key to see the definition:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\User Agent
```

Look for it under the `Pre-Platform` and `Post-Platform` keys.

> Many factors affect the user-agent string, including OEM vendors, carriers, network administrators, and user preferences.
>
> Additional tokens can be added to the user-agent string by using the Registry Editor to create new string values under the Pre-Platform key or Post-Platform key. The value name should be the complete token; the value data is ignored. Tokens added to the Pre-Platform key appear before the platform token in the final user-agent string. Tokens added to the Post-Platform key appear after the platform token in the final user-agent string. Multiple tokens in either the Pre-Platform key or Post-Platform key are displayed in an unpredictable order.
>
> Earlier versions of Internet Explorer included feature tokens defined using the Pre-Platform and Post-Platform keys part of the user-agent string during the HTTP negotiation process. Over time, this lead to overly long user-agent strings, which in turn created problems for certain web servers. Problems usually appeared when user-agent strings were longer than 256 characters. As of Internet Explorer 9, the user-agent string no longer includes feature tokens during HTTP negotiation. Feature tokens are included in the value returned by the userAgent property of the navigator object. Applications that rely on the earlier behavior should be modified accordingly.

**References**

- [Device Detector Github repo](https://github.com/podigee/device_detector)
- [Internet Explorer compatibility cookbook: User-agent string changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh869301)
- [Understanding user-agent strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms537503.aspx)
- [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253)

Comment: I think they are "vendor id" or "OEM id" strings. MATM / MATMJS seems to be Toshiba.