# Force IE 11 “User agent string” to IE10 or less

Tags: compatibility, internet-explorer-11

We are having a problem rendering DataWindow table with our website in IE11. 
I tried to test the pages trough IE11 Developer tools. Setting document mode doesn't help, but setting UserAgentString to anything less than IE11 produces correct webpages.
It's not possible to modifie DW behaviour and it seems DW .dll is connected to this UserAgentString parameter.

Is there any way how to force IE to have UserAgentString anything less than IE11??

As I read web there is no direct way to set UserAgentString parameter, but maybe setting ie.browser file in AppData folder could help in this. Do you have any idea how to set this file to get required behavior??

Comment: If you described the problem we might have a better chance of helping. Maybe it's a CSS issue.

Comment: I tried to play with css, but got no results. Nothing changes DW from overleaking the page to right. DW in this just ignore css. With AgentString mode set to 10 it DW width renders correctly and it has horizontal scrollbar in it. Scrollbar is generated by DW itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the User Agent registry keys to prepend the old user agent string to the new one:

> Earlier versions of Internet Explorer included feature tokens defined using the Pre-Platform and Post-Platform keys part of the user-agent string during the HTTP negotiation process. Over time, this lead to overly long user-agent strings, which in turn created problems for certain web servers. Problems usually appeared when user-agent strings were longer than 256 characters. As of Internet Explorer 9, the user-agent string no longer includes feature tokens during HTTP negotiation. Feature tokens are included in the value returned by the userAgent property of the navigator object. Applications that rely on the earlier behavior should be modified accordingly.
>   Note  The user-agent string should not be used to indicate the presence of optional software or features. Custom version vectors, which can be detected using conditional comments, provide a more appropriate mechanism.
>
> You can also override certain tokens of the user-agent string by adding values to the following registry key.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
   SOFTWARE
      Microsoft
         Windows
            CurrentVersion
               Internet Settings
                  5.0
                     User Agent
                        (default) = "Mozilla/4.0"
                        Compatible = "compatible"
                        Platform = "Windows NT 5.1"
                        Version = "MSIE 6.0"
                        Pre Platform
                           Token = Value
                        Post Platform
                           Token = Value
```

> The default value of the User Agent key replaces the application name and application version tokens reported in the user-agent string. Be aware that the first seven characters are used for the application name, and the remaining characters specify the application version token.
>
> The Compatible, Platform, and Version values replace the corresponding tokens in the user-agent string.
>
> Additional tokens can be added to the user-agent string by using the Registry Editor to create new string values under the Pre-Platform key or Post-Platform key. The value name should be the complete token; the value data is ignored. Tokens added to the Pre-Platform key appear before the platform token in the final user-agent string. Tokens added to the Post-Platform key appear after the platform token in the final user-agent string. Multiple tokens in either the Pre-Platform key or Post-Platform key are displayed in an unpredictable order.
>
> Note
>     If the browser is open when these keys are changed, the changes don't take effect until all browser windows are closed; this includes applications hosting the WebBrowser Control. Be aware that applications hosting the WebBrowser Control can override the Internet Explorer user-agent string without modifying it.

**References**

- [Understanding user-agent strings: User-agent registry keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx#UARegistry)
- [What is MATM in my User-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414484/1113772)